# How to install python dependency when using google-cloud-ml-engine notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I am on google-cloud-ml notebook. Trying to install pandas_ml in order to import it.

I read https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/dependencies tried both options (terminal and a separate installation notebook). None of those solutions work for me

```py
#either
pip install pandas_ml #terminal
#or
!pip install pandas_ml #notebook
```

Comment: Can you specify or provide more details what "none ... work for me" means? Which steps do have performed? Are there any problems or error messages?

Comment: Sure, I am getting an `ImportError` when trying to `from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
since I'm using Python 3.5 I had to use pip3 instead of pip

Answer (score -1):

`!pip` will install your packages on the system level and not in your notebook kernel. Try this instead:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip3 install pandas_ml
```

Eventually, Google MLE notebooks will support `%pip`.

More information can be found on Jake VanderPlas's blog: [Installing Python Packages from a Jupyter Notebook](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/).